# Prove that $⇒$ alone is suﬃcient to deﬁne $∨$

Tags: logic

To show this is true, we are asked to prove that $A∨B$ is equivalent to an expression in which the only connective is $⇒$. It seems that we cannot even involve $¬$.

I have no idea to deal with it so far. Could someone help? Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am wondering if it is a conjunction. The question does not mention this sign.

Comment: $\lor$ is *disjunction* : $p \lor q$ is *false* exactly when both $p$ abd $q$ are *false*.

Comment: $(A \to B) \to B$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am sorry that I am new to logic and cannot get it immediately. Could you please give a proof that they are equivalent? Thanks!

Comment: Check it with truth table.

Comment: Use truth table or the fact that $p \to q$ is the same as $\lnot p \lor q$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I see that (A⇒B) ⇒B is equivalent to A∨B, thanks! Moreover, may I ask another question to show that in the case that we have only  $¬$ and $⇔$ , we are not able to define all connectives? Could you please have a look to this highly related question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172950/show-that-%c2%ac-and-%e2%87%94-together-are-not-su%ef%ac%83cient-to-de%ef%ac%81ne-all-the-connectives

Comment: @Y.X. If you only have $\neg$ and $\leftrightarrow$ then any truth-function defined over two or more variables will have an even number of $T$'s (and (therefore) an even number of $F$'s as well) in the truth-table. You can fairly easily prove that by induction.